# Why doesn't my fill of fills array work properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I use a fill function inside a fill function to create a 2 dimensional array, any changes into any coordinates of this array will change all of his respective column.

But when I use `Array.from()`, which uses a `.map` function as parameter, it works just fine.
Why does this happen?
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkPiT.png)

Comment: reffer this section first [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should include your code sample in your question, rather than in external links.

Comment: `.fill()` will fill the array with the reference to that array.

Comment: Your `.from` use a function create new Array, but `.fill` reference all index to parameter(same)